# Is there anything wrong in manipulating GUI controls from another thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I always hear that I should only manipulate GUI controls from the GUI thread, but I do not understand what is wrong in doing so from another thread.

I mean if I want to change a Window's title bar text, all I need to do is to send a message to the Window's message queue. So what is wrong in doing that from another thread?

Comment: When you send a message to a window, the window procedure is executed on the thread that owns the window. The system takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HWND has an affinity to the thread that creates it.  Only the owning thread can destroy the HWND, and only the owning thread can receive messages that are *posted* to the HWND via the owning thread's message queue.  If a message is *sent* direct to the HWND by the owning thread, the HWND's window procedure is called immediately, otherwise it is dispatched through the owning thread's message loop (not to be confused with the owning thread's message queue).  So either way, the HWND's window procedure is always executed in the context of the owning thread.

The owning thread may have also associated data with the HWND, or uses notifications from the HWND to manipulate other data/HWNDs, that are not protected from concurrent access across threads.

So only the owning thread should ever manipulate the HWND and its data in any way.

Now, there are some exceptions to this, like `WM_SETTEXT` for instance.  But unless you know for sure that any given message is thread-safe, assume it is not and delegate all access to the HWND through the owning thread.

Comment: "So only the owning thread should ever manipulate the HWND and its data in any way" But how can another thread manipulate the HWND if the HWND's window procedure is always executed in the context of the owning thread?

Comment: By sending unsafe window messages directly to the HWND, manipulate its content, etc.  Things that can get out of sync if they are done concurrently in multiple threads.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand what you mean. All I know so far is if you call `SendMessage()` from multiple threads, the multiple calls will be executed sequentially (since the window procedure is always executed in the context of the owning thread as you have said), so how can such behavior not be safe in any way? Maybe you are not talking about `SendMessage()`, but rather talking about things like getting a pointer to an "EDIT" control buffer and manipulating it directly from multiple threads?

Comment: Sure *individual* messages are processed serially. But if a thread has to send multiple messages to perform an operation on the HWND, but a task switch occurs between messages and another thread changes the HWND's state, invalidating the first thread's operation.

Comment: So there is nothing *technically* wrong with it, just sometimes the logic can be broken, correct?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Can't you put the multiple SendMessage() calls in a critical section?

Comment: @rony_t: all threads involved, including the UI thread, would have to wrap all access to the HWND within the critical section, and that is not feasible for UIs. But if you separate your data logic from your UI logic, then protect your data, the UI becomes a non-issue as it won't need to be accessed across threads anymore.

Comment: So the best way to manipulate UI elements is to send a message to the UI thread telling it to execute a specified code (for example, I can place my code in a function and send a function pointer to the UI thread), just like `Synchronize()` in C++Builder?

Comment: That can work, though there are many ways to synchronize between threads.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you want to avoid is graphics lag caused by the program doing something else. Apart from that, it is a program design issue. If the other thread hangs, waiting for whatever it is usually doing, then no SendMessage() will be executed.

You have then created a tight coupling between the graphic update and whatever unrelated task there is which keeps the other thread busy. Program design-wise, it doesn't make any sense to have for example the file handling thread updating graphics, even if doing so doesn't necessarily cause graphics lag.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "manipulate" UI elements from other threads than the UI thread - if you're sending MESSAGES you will indirectly queue commands which are then processed on the messagequeue and *maybe* cause a state change of your targeted UI element - which is automatically done on the UI thread.

There is nothing wrong with multithreaded UI element-control as long as you know what you're doing - one pretty simple way to achieve it is via windows messages, but these can get tedious if your current task is somewhat complex; in these cases its often better to create a central class which accepts your "UI control commands" from arbitrary threads, sequentializes and executes them on the UI thread, if possible.
You can also temporarily switch your thread context onto the main UI-thread, effectively converting your current thread into a UI - thread : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
I have never used this and this approach seems quite ... questionable to me

Comment: Not quite right. Sent messages are not queued. They are dispatched by `GetMessage` or similar functions.

Comment: GetMessage dispatches nothing, the `Dispatcher` dispatches messages - sequentially and blocking, A sequentially read/writen buffer is a queue.

Comment: No. @David is correct. `GetMessage` dispatches cross thread sent messages.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx): *The function dispatches incoming sent messages until a posted message is available for retrieval.* Yes, you can consider synchronous messages are being processed in a queue but when we talk about the queue in relation to messages we typically mean the message queue, the queue that `PostMessage` adds to.

Comment: ... and for sent messages that do not cross thread boundaries, the system calls directly into the window procedure. In this case, `SendMessage` dispatches the message.