# UI thread and deadlock

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

I have a UI thread, and one or more worker threads. I want the worker thread to write to the UI controls, and read from the UI controls. The way I decided to implement it is by using `SendMessage()`.

The worker thread starts when the main thread starts, and terminates when the main thread terminates (this could cause a deadlock if I tried to send a message (and wait) to the worker thread asking it to terminate and the worker thread issued a `SendMessage()` at the same time, but closing my program will terminate the worker thread automatically).

In the UI thread, I will not wait for the worker thread to terminate (or waiting for anything for that matter), so I believe that no deadlock will occur.

**My question is: is there a situation that I am missing where a deadlock could happen?**

Note that I don't mind with the other problems caused by using `SendMessage()` instead of `PostMessage()`, such as blocking the worker thread for some time instead of just posting a message to the UI thread message queue and continue executing its code.

---

This is the reason why I am using the synchronous `SendMessage()` in the worker thread and not the asynchronous `PostMessage()`:

Say I have the following pseudo-code:

```
/* Thread A */

// Get content of hEdit into str
// DeleteFile(str)
```

If I use `PostMessage()`, then I could reach `DeleteFile(str)` before the content of `hEdit` are placed into `str`.

Comment: Normally worker threads produce data, which is then passed to the UI, which in turn displays that data.

Comment: @David Heffernan So I guess they are just other threads. They are IOCP threads in fact.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Try to avoid such direct coupling with the UI.

Comment: @David Heffernan What do you mean by that? (I am new to GUI programming).

Comment: Stop trying to get the worker thread to drive the UI thread. Have the worker thread update a non-visual data structure, and let the UI thread present it. Perhaps use message passing (not necessarily the Windows message queue) to pass data from worker. But the worker thread should not need to know anything about the UI. Keep the worker thread ignorant of the UI.

Comment: @David Heffernan So when I receive some data from a socket, I place this data in some data structure, and then the UI thread gets this data and update the UI controls? But how will the UI thread knows that there are pending data?

Comment: Various ways to do that. Posting a message via the message queue is one way. Setting an event another. Having the UI thread poll with a timer another. Kind of depends on your needs.

Comment: @David Heffernan Also, if the worker thread needs to read data from a control, should I also have the UI thread place this data into some data structure, and then have the worker thread read it? And wouldn't this mean that I have to wait until the data is read? (because when displaying data to the UI controls I can just continue executing the rest of the code)

Comment: Have the worker ask for the data. Your goal is for the worker to know nothing about the UI.

Comment: @David Heffernan I don't think that this approach is necessary for a small program such as mine. Is there a technical problem in having the worker thread access the UI controls directly?

Comment: Decoupling like this is always better in my view. You disagree? Fine. That's your call.

Comment: @David Heffernan I don't have any experience with this approach to disagree with you (this is the first time I heard of it). I just think that I don't need to implement it just because I have 5 places where I need to display something to the UI controls and 3 placed where I need to read something from the UI controls

Comment: How can you ask this question, outlining existing problems, and then turn around and say that you do not need a solution? David has provided the information you need, so go ahead and decouple the calculation kernel from your UI.

Comment: @IInspectable Can you tell me why the approach of accessing the UI controls directly is wrong (in my case) so that I can follow the decoupling approach?

Comment: In that case you may wish to [read up on your approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29012941/1889329). At any rate, if you insist that you wish to shoot yourself in the foot, go right ahead. I'm out.

Comment: @IInspectable The accepted answer in that thread says that the UI manipulation code will ultimately be executed in the context of the UI thread. So I don't see a problem for this approach other the the ones I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: The accepted answer says: *"So only the owning thread should ever manipulate the HWND and its data in any way."*

Comment: @IInspectable When I send a `WM_SETTEXT` message to change a Window title, this is not manipulating the `HWND`, correct? So does "manipulate the HWND" means something like destroying the Window?

Comment: A `HWND` is an index into a kernel-controlled table of `WND` structures. The window title is part of the `WND` structure, as are parent and owner window, position, or the size. Any change to this structure is colloquially referred to as *manipulating the `HWND`*. `WM_SETTEXT` works, due to a compatibility shim, that was implemented, because too many people like yourself insisted, that they knew what they were doing. If you absolutely must do the Wrong Thing, keep in mind that you are taking a dependency on a compatibility shim. Not entirely wise for new software.

Comment: @IInspectable I have heard from many programmers contradictory statements about whether it is a bad idea to use `SendMessage()` from a worker thread or not. So I guess to be on the safe side, I will not use it. However, is there a problem in using `SendMessage()` to send a user-defined message?

Comment: You are reasoning at the wrong level of abstraction. Calling `SendMessage` from a thread is not, per se, wrong. What is wrong is baking knowledge of the UI into your worker threads. As @IInspectable says, go ahead and do that if you want. My advice is that you don't do so.

Comment: So long as the UI thread does not exit the message loop until the worker thread has exited, you shouldn't have any issues with deadlocking.  However, if by "terminate the worker thread automatically" you mean using TerminateThread, that's extremely dangerous and could cause a deadlock.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I think we may be confusing the OP at this point.  Your advice [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29577983/886887) seems to contradict your advice in these comments?

Comment: @Harry Here we are talking more about threading design within an app. In the answer there I was saying that SendMessage could be used and would work. I wasn't necessarily blessing it as a design choice. I also talked about cross process use.

Comment: @Harry Johnston What I meant is that because I am using `SendMessage()` in the worker threads, then if when closing the program I try to send a message to the worker threads asking them to close, this could cause a deadlock if a a worker thread is blocking on a `SendMessage()`, so I figured that if I did not closed the worker threads and just closed the program then the worker threads will also be closed automatically. (bad thing to do I know but better than `TerminateThread()`!).

Comment: @Harry Johnston Anyway, this does not matter anymore as I have come up with another solution: use `PostMessage()` instead of `SendMessage()` in the worker threads to send user-defined messages, and then wait on two events: one to be signaled when the user-defined message is processed, and the other to be signaled when closing the program (to break the "`PostMessage()` block" if any, and hence no deadlock will occur).

Comment: Yes, that should work.